# performance of UDF in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a high performance calculations which require custom functions.

As a first stage I am trying to profile the effect of using UDF and I am getting weird results.

I created a simple test (in https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/6100413009427980/1838590056414286/3882373005101896/latest.html)

Basically I create a dataframe using the range option with 50M records and cache it.

I then do a filter to find those smaller than 10 and count them. Once by doing column < 10 and once by doing it via UDF.

I ran each action 10 times to get a good time estimate.

What I found was that both methods took around the same time: ~4 seconds.

I also tried it in an on premise cluster I have (8 nodes, using yarn, each node with ~40GB memory and plenty of cores). There I got a result of 1 second for the first option and 8 for the second.

First I do not understand how is it that on the databricks cluster I got the same performance. Shouldn't the UDF be much slower? After all, there is no codegen so I should be seeing a much slower process.

Second I don't understand the huge differences between the two cluters: In one I have almost the same time and the other an x8 difference.

Lastly, I was trying to figure out how to write a custom function natively (i.e. the way spark does it). I tried to look at the code for spark and came out with something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.InternalRow 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.TypeCheckResult 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.{CodegenContext, ExprCode} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.TypeUtils 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 
import org.apache.spark.util.Utils 
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions._

case class genf(child: Expression) extends UnaryExpression with Predicate with ImplicitCastInputTypes {

  override def inputTypes: Seq[AbstractDataType] = Seq(IntegerType)

  override def toString: String = s"$child < 10"

  override def eval(input: InternalRow): Any = { 
    val value = child.eval(input) 
    if (value == null) 
    { 
      false
    } else {
      child.dataType match {
        case IntegerType => value.asInstanceOf[Int] < 10 
      } 
    } 
  }

  override def doGenCode(ctx: CodegenContext, ev: ExprCode): ExprCode = {
   defineCodeGen(ctx, ev, c => s"($c) < 10") 
  } 
}
```

This, however doesn't work as it would only work from within the sql package (for example AbstractDataType is private).

Is this code even in the right direction? How would I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get this to work?